# How to dispatch an event from an event in re-frame

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I followed this example:
https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/FAQs/PollADatabaseEvery60.md

And here is my interval handler

```
(defonce interval-handler
  (fn [{:keys [action id frequency event]}]
    (let [live-intervals (atom {})]
      (condp = action
        :start (swap! live-intervals assoc id (js/setInterval #(re-frame/dispatch event) frequency))
        :end (do (js/clearInterval (get live-intervals id))
                 (swap! live-intervals dissoc id))))))

(re-frame/reg-fx
  :interval
  interval-handler)
```

I'm trying to dispatch this interval event from another event right here:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
  :start-playing
  (fn [db _]
    (re-frame/dispatch [:interval {:action :start
                       :id :some-awesome-id
                       :frequency 1000
                       :event [:tick]}])
    (assoc db :is-playing? true
           :fake (random-active-color db)
           :real (random-active-color db))))
```

but it says `re-frame: no  :event  handler registered for:  :interval`

Is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:interval` is an effect, not an event. To invoke an effect, you need to include it as a key in the effects map returned by your event handler - not emit another event with the effect's key:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-fx
  :start-playing
  (fn [{:keys [db]} _]
    {:interval {:action :start
                :id :some-awesome-id
                :event [:tick]}]
     :db (assoc db :is-playing? true
                   :fake (random-active-color db)
                   :real (random-active-color db))}))
```

Above event handler will return a map describing two effects:

- `:db` - updating the app db to a new value (provided as the `:db` value)
- `:interval` - re-frame will call your effect handler (`interval-handler`) with the value of `:interval` entry in the effects map

Comment: You're missing `db` as the first arg to `assoc`. It won't let me edit it cause the change is too small...